# Difference in losses between tensorflow.model.fit() and tensorflow.model.train_on_batch()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have built two equal simple CNN models in `tensorflow`, however the first one is trained with the `model.fit()` method and the second one with `model.train_on_batch()` method, for equal number of epochs (5) and equal batch size (128). For the first model I have also implemented a custom callback that returns a list of losses for every batch:

```
output = list()
class LossHistory(Callback):
   def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
      output.append(logs['loss'])
```

I also save the losses which method `model.fit()` outputs (this is on every epoch end). So to summarize:

- Model 1 (with the `model.fit()` method) outputs the standard losses on every epoch end (**red curve**) and losses on every batch end (from the callback, **blue curve**).
- Model 2 (with the `model.train_on_batch()` method) outputs losses which are saved to a list after every call on this method (**green curve**).

Plot, where the mentioned losses are shown:
[image: Comparison of the learning curves]

I am wondering why the `callback` method returns learning curve which is not noisy at all compared to the `model.train_on_batch()` method and why are those steps present. Shouldn't the blue and the green curve be more similar as both of them get their values at the end of the batch? I assume that my callback is not returning me what I really want (maybe some kind of smoothing or averaging).

Thank you for your help in advance!

**Edit**: Just noticed that my learning curve from the `model.fit()` method (red curve) was plotted in the wrong way. Now makes more sense, but still I am a confused in the difference between them.

Comment: Did you set your seeds to make sure the random numbers  aren't the cause of the difference?